# RPi PWM issues - (re)start results in oscillating pin

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio, pwm

I'm building a sauna controlling mechanism, controlled by the Pi, using PWM and solid-state relays.
Works fine, but after a while, the PWM breaks down.
At this moment, when I run the program and the PWM starts, it works at first; changing the duty cycle also works fine.
When I stop and re-start the PWM however, it results in an oscillating pin, no expected output.

This is the testcode:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

print("PWM start - GPIO setup")
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(2)

print("PWM start - set PWM")
sauna_pwm0 = GPIO.PWM(16, 0.5)
time.sleep(2)

print("DC 20")
sauna_pwm0.start(20)
time.sleep(5)

print("PWM stop (DC 0)")
sauna_pwm0.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
time.sleep(3)

print("DC 20")
sauna_pwm0.ChangeDutyCycle(20)
time.sleep(5)

print("PWM stop")
sauna_pwm0.stop()
time.sleep(3)

# ---
print("GPIO cleanup")
GPIO.cleanup()
time.sleep(2)

print("PWM restart - GPIO setup")
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(2)

print("PWM restart - set PWM")
sauna_pwm0 = GPIO.PWM(16, 0.5)
time.sleep(2)
# ---

print("DC 20")
sauna_pwm0.start(20)  # DC is NOT 20, but PWM is oscillating at high frequency
time.sleep(5)

print("PWM stop")
sauna_pwm0.stop()
time.sleep(3)

print("GPIO cleanup")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

At the second "start(20)" the pin does not what is expected.
When I stop and re-start the program, it works again (up until the 2nd start).

There is a lot out there on PWM not functioning as it should - it is suggested to use ChangeDutyCycle(0) instead of stop().

Even when I do not cleanup() in between the starts, and "just restart" after a stop(), it oscillates.
(in this case, the code between the # --- is commented out --> same behaviour)

**Is the conclusion that PWM is just too buggy to use?** (also see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=277137)
Should I use another PWM mechanism?
(https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster, for example? didn't try it yet, though)

Or is there something wrong with the way I use the GPIO module?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Joan may have a better solution but it is difficult to understand your code. Why freq = 0.5Hz (ChangeFrequency says frequency - frequency in Hz (freq > 1.0)? Why stop and start and try to create new PWM object? Under the wraps PWM creates new threads, but given the nature of python timing can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Frequency is 0.5 meaning 1 pulse every 2 seconds - every 1% will thus be 20ms (Europe 50Hz net frequency) meaning 1 sinus - that's fast en granulate enough to modulate a saunaheater (9kW) - start & stop with new PWM object (in between # ---) was just a test - removing this yields the same results

Comment: My comment was that the documentation states freq > 1.0. The PWM works if you don't try to stop; just set duty cycle to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug of the RPi.GPIO Python module.

Look through [RPi.GPIO tickets](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/).

You could use the [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) or [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (if you use pigpio as the backend).  pigpio is likely to be pre-installed as is gpiozero.

For a non-daemon based alternative to pigpio you could use the [lgpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html).